# Bootstrap modal not showing up on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

when I try to load a modal in Bootstrap, it shows up when I refresh the page but doesn't show up when I click on the button. I'd like my modal to pop up only when the user clicks on the button.

My **html** file is set up as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>my title here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/Highcharts-5.0.14/code/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/Highcharts-5.0.14/code/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style_charts_black.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>
```

I've copied this code from the Bootstrap tutorial website:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="float:right; margin-right:100px">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>$('#myModal').modal('show')</script>
```

I do not get any jquery errors in the javascript console. I've also tried to change the last line above to *.modal('toggle')* but it didn't help.

Comment: dont need to use this  **$('#myModal').modal('show')**

Comment: **<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="float:right; margin-right:100px">
Launch demo modal
</button>** This button **toggle** the **target** element with **id=#myModal**

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the data toggle in the html tag and 
write the

```js
$('#myModal').modal('show')
or
$('#myModal').modal('toggle')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, you need to include the js files in the `<body>` tag, not the head.

From their documentation:

> Add our JavaScript plugins, jQuery, and Tether near the end of your pages, right before the closing body tag.

Here is the link where I found that info:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/

And a codepen of the js files included in the body and your code working correctly:

https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/MEGgJE

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, if you just want the modal to be activated when you click the button, you do not need the script

> $('#myModal').modal('show')

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>GSMA Intelligence &mdash; Visuals</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```